Help finding under cabinet replacement light
Can anyone tell me what type of connector this is?
I am trying to replace a 36” under cabinet light that is connected to a GE Polymeric Outlet Box.


The connector alone is of little help. What is the rating on the power supply connected to it? Does it connect directly to 120 VAC or 240 VAC mains? Is there a power supply at the other end of that connector? What is its rating, or make and model?

Is the "GE Polymeric Outlet Box" one of these things? https://www.gelighting.com/led-lights/bulbs/ge-junction-box-add-accessory-premium-direct-wireplug-fixtures

Look at molex.com to get an idea of how many types and variations of this connector there are.  It's impossible to identify from a photo.   You need more info, at least the series number of which there are hundreds.  For cabinet lighting it might be easier to replace both sides of the connector with anything you choose.  You need to get the voltage and current rating and polarity right, most other variables won't matter.

If it's the system identified by @Triplefault you must buy complete linking cables, not make them from parts.   That system used surface mounted high voltage link cables.   There's no reason to make your own.

Its a molex type connector. Take a it to an electronic hobby store.

The type is called Molex.
You have special version with round and square combo plugs.
From the photo that is unclear you have male and female pins.
That is usually done when you want to keep the polarity oriented.
Those pins can be exchanged if needed.
Those type of plugs are often used in automotive so check those stores

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact you are wrong, there is only one logical reason to use round and square combo plugs, it is to keep the connection oriented

A person with some sense would orient the rentention clip on the male and female sides of the connector, but I suppose if the plugs were the same shape some person with little mechanical sense could plug them together backwards.
